# Add doctrine fixture in composer.json

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixture

How can I add two doctrine ficture to composer.json?
I think I have to include in:

```
"require": {
}
```

I have my fixture in src/AppBundle/DataFixture/ORM/

Comment: How are fixtures related to composer? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a dependency management tool, not a build automation tool.

You can use a task runner like [Phing](https://www.phing.info/) or [Robo](http://robo.li/) and have it run composer install then your fixtures command or any other command you need.